# How does java distinguish that the character is full-width or half-width?

Tags: java

I have these codes with the same variable names but the only difference is one type is full-width and the other is half-width. I was shocked that Java supports full-width characters as variable names. I was wondering how can Java differentiate the two characters.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ｘ = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] ｙ = { 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] y = { 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] ｚ = new int[ｘ.length];
        int[] z = new int[ｘ.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ｚ.length; i++) {
            ｚ[i] = ｘ[i] + ｙ[i];
            z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
        }
        System.out.println(ｚ);
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: They are different characters. Java would need special handling to consider them the same, not the other way around.

Comment: Java Language Specification: [3.8. Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8): "*Letters and digits may be drawn from the **entire** Unicode character set, ...Two identifiers are the same only if, after ignoring characters that are ignorable, the identifiers have the **same Unicode character** for each letter or digit.*"

Comment: They look different enough to me. For a _real_ challenge, use Greek or Cyrillic letters for variable names. Like `ϳ`, `j` or `j`.

Comment: @MrLister [That is so very confusing that it is scary](https://i.giphy.com/media/gOHxskuYRcg3m/giphy.webp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java supports Unicode in source code, so [`ｘ`](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%EF%BD%98) (`u'\uff58'`) is much more different than [`x`](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=x) (`u'x'`)

Essentially different characters, same as having `int[] a` & `int[] b`

But for readability, this is a huge problem. Even though two different variables, it is very easy for another user to confuse these names. It is better stick to the basic Latin letters in their simple forms as much as possible within the source code.

Comment: @John3136 yeah, lol, I got confused in the exact same manner!! Imagine an intern getting mad with that... #beware

Comment: If I look really closely, my browser is rendering them slightly differently - almost like one in uppercase and one in lower? Not 100% sure though...

Answer (score 2):

From *The Java Tutorials* trail *Learning the Java Language*, lesson *Language Basics*, topic [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "_".

So in java code, you can even write variable names in [Klingon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_scripts)

Comment: [For the honor of the Empire!](https://dadap.github.io/pIqaD-tools/universal-transliterator/?xifan=woz%20baxvad)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your source code is encoded in UTF-8 (or some other "extended" character set) so the codes for ｘ and x are different (the machine does not care about the graphical representation of the character but the internal code).